# opencv rectangular on Google Colab

Tags: opencv3.0, google-colaboratory

On Google Colab I can have a picture shown inline using the following

```
!curl -o logo.png https://colab.research.google.com/img/colab_favicon_256px.png
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('logo.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
cv2_imshow(img)
```

I would like to draw a rectangular on the picture (inline)

```
tt=cv2.rectangle(img, (210, 826), (270, 900), (250, 255, 0), 20 )
cv2_imshow(tt)
```

but this does not work

Answer (score 3):

Some problems here:

1. The .png is 256x256, so your coordinates are unreasonable (mostly off-screen).
2. The .png has transparency so the lack of a fourth coordinate in your color spec means using an alpha of zero, so the rectangle is not visible.
3. `cv2.rectangle` modifies its first argument, so better to keep referring to `img` and avoid the confusion of expecting it to remain unchanged by referring to `tt` later.

Here's example code that results in a visible rectangle:

```
!curl -s -o logo.png https://colab.research.google.com/img/colab_favicon_256px.png
import cv2
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
img = cv2.imread('logo.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
print(img.shape)
cv2.rectangle(img, (128, 128), (163, 172), (0, 255, 0, 255), 2)
cv2_imshow(img)
```

[image]